# Using Stripe for payments between users

Tags: oauth, flask, stripe-connect

I'm working on a **Flask** application where I would like to use **Stripe** as a way for users send/receive payments  to/from each other.  Stripe Connect using Shared Customers seems like the way to make this happen, but I'm a little confused on the flow.  It seems I will need to create both a connected account *and* a Customer to be associated with each user in my application.

This is how I understand it should work:

- Through the OAuth flow, user *A* creates or connects their existing account with the application, and an `access_token` is received.  This connected account is where they will receive money when paid by a Customer.
- If user *A* wants to send a payment to user *B*, then using **stripe.js**, user *A* enters a credit card, which is returned to the application in the form of a token.
- This token is used to create a new Customer, which is stored on the platform account.
- The `customer id` for user *A*, along with the user *B's* connected account `access_token` can be used to create a new token to be used as the `source` of a Charge.

I've seen [examples](https://gist.github.com/kaiserama/a458aabcc3b3067ce308) of how this can all be done.

So I think I should be saving an `access_token` and a `customer id` for each user in my application.  But something about this doesn't feel right.  It seems like Customers are meant to be used when the user doesn't necessarily have a stripe account and won't ever be receiving money. ***Is there a simpler approach where I can just charge user A's connected account on behalf of B's connected account?***

Answer (score 1):

When you use stripe to create a credit card token, you can create a customer with it or a charge. Creating a customer will allow you to charge that customer in the future without generating another token by passing the customer_id instead of a source.

I think the answer to your question is mostly no. You can avoid creating a customer, which in this case is probably a good idea, by generating a new token each time and creating the charge with that.